# Optimal file format for USB3 memory

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, usb-3, file-format

Which is the best choice and why for formatting a USB3 memory stick?
FAT32 was the out of the box, but the file size limit is a to small.

- FAT32
- NTFS
- exFAT

Size, speed and stability are good measurements.

Im using a SanDisk Extreme memory stick.

Comment: FAT32 will work on most computers, but like you said the file size is limited to 4gbs. NTFS not only supports larger files sizes, but also supports Security features (read, write, access permissions) where fat32 does not. With NTFS you may not be able to access the drive on differenent operating sytems such as Mac/Linux without installing additional software. I am not sure about exFat other then it isn't really overly common, but will work for most people. FAT32 is probably the best bet if you don't need to worry about the file size limitation, and want it to work on most computers.

Comment: They all have their pros and cons and you will have to decide based on those pros and cons...

Comment: Might be of interest: http://superuser.com/questions/665452/recommended-settings-to-format-usb-sticks/665460#665460